# Dynamic environment variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am refactoring some code that I think is hacky and not sure the best way to handle this.

My original code is:

```
def some_url
    if Rails.env == "development"
      url = "http://12.12.12.12/something/#{self.id}"
    else
      url = "https://www.#{ENV['DOMAIN']}/something/#{self.id}?trk=0&updated_at=#{self.updated_at}"
    end
end
```

I don't like the `if Rails.env == "development"` portion and I am trying to extract this URL to an environment variable.  My first attempt was to do this was:

```
def some_url
    "#{ENV['DOMAIN']}/something/#{self.id}/#{ENV['URL_PARAMS']}"
end
```

Everything is fine until I get to the end with the `updated_at`.  I need it for every environment except development.  So, I can't add it as an environment variable since it is dynamic.  Adding it conditionally doesn't make sense since it doesn't do any better than I already have.  Any thoughts as to how to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you conditionally need the param, so I don't see any easy way to do it other than via a conditional.  Personally, I'd maybe go this route:

```
def some_url(params = {})
  base_url = "#{ENV['DOMAIN']}/something/#{self.id}/#{ENV['URL_PARAMS']}"

  params.merge!(updated_at: self.updated_at) unless Rails.env.development?

  base_url << "?#{params.to_query}" unless params.blank?
end
```

Comment: I like this approach.  I can see that there is no way to get around the conditional so I think this is the cleanest/nicest option.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a conditional there. The only way I can think of without is to use a regular expression to match "updated_at=" from your ENV variable and sub it for "updated_at=#{self.updated_at}"

Like so:

```
def some_url
    "#{ENV['DOMAIN']}/something/#{self.id}/#{ENV['URL_PARAMS'].sub('updated_at=', "updated_at=#{self.updated_at}")}"
end
```

Comment: This is a good option as well, but not sure I want to do a regex, I still like the idea though. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yeah, I think the other solution is way cleaner